# How to make shades appear seamlessly in jetPack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When the vertical gradient meets white to black + the horizontal gradient of the specific color results in non-smath shades
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKAdF.png)
If you remove the hue value, the shaping will clearly show[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOe8X.png)
This is code :

```
.drawBehind {
                val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(bitmap.value)
                val drawRectF = RectF(0F, 0F, sizeWidth, sizeHeight)
                val hueValue = android.graphics.Color.HSVToColor(floatArrayOf(hue, 1F, 0F)) 

                val horizontalGradientPaint = LinearGradient(
                    drawRectF.left,
                    drawRectF.top,
                    drawRectF.right,
                    drawRectF.top,
                    -0x1,
                    hueValue,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
                )
                val verticalGradientPaint = LinearGradient(
                    drawRectF.left, drawRectF.top, drawRectF.left, drawRectF.bottom,
                    -0x1,
                    -0x1000000,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                )

                canvas.drawRect(
                    drawRectF,
                    Paint()
                        .asFrameworkPaint()
                        .apply {
                            shader = ComposeShader(
                                verticalGradientPaint,
                                horizontalGradientPaint,
                                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
                            )
                            isAntiAlias = true
                            isDither = true
                        }
                )

                drawImage(
                    bitmap.value.asImageBitmap()
                )

                drawCircle(
                    color = strokeUpdateColor(
                        selectorPositionX.floatValue,
                        selectorPositionY.floatValue,
                        sizeWidth,
                        sizeHeight
                    ),
                    radius = selectorSize,
                    style = Stroke(
                        width = selectorSize / 3.2F,
                    ),
                    center = Offset(selectorPositionX.floatValue, selectorPositionY.floatValue)
                )

            }
```

And this is a full code :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.ComposeShader
import android.graphics.LinearGradient
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.graphics.Shader
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableFloatStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawBehind
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Paint
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


@Composable
fun ColorPickerTest() {
    val colorState = remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }

    Column( modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(
                color = colorState.value
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp))
        PanelBlockPicker(
            width = 350.dp,
            height = 350.dp,
            selectorSize = 32F,
            hue = 0F,
            onColorPicked = {
                colorState.value = it
            }
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun PanelBlockPicker(
    width: Dp,
    height: Dp,
    selectorSize: Float,
    hue: Float = 0F,
    onColorPicked: (Color) -> Unit,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val sizeWidth = with(density) { width.toPx() }
    val sizeHeight = with(density) { height.toPx() }

    val bitmap = remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            Bitmap.createBitmap(sizeWidth.toInt(), sizeHeight.toInt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        )
    }
    val selectorPositionX = remember { mutableFloatStateOf(sizeWidth - (selectorSize * 1.4F)) }
    val selectorPositionY = remember { mutableFloatStateOf(selectorSize * 1.4F) }
    val isDragging = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    fun setSelectorPosition(x: Float, y: Float, maxWidth: Float, maxHeight: Float) {
        selectorPositionX.floatValue = x.coerceIn(0F, maxWidth)
        selectorPositionY.floatValue = y.coerceIn(0F, maxHeight)
    }

    Surface {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(width, height)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    when {
                        change.pressed -> {
                            isDragging.value = true
                            setSelectorPosition(
                                x = change.position.x, y = change.position.y, sizeWidth, sizeHeight
                            )
                        }

                        isDragging.value -> {
                            val newX = selectorPositionX.floatValue + dragAmount.x
                            val newY = selectorPositionY.floatValue + dragAmount.y
                            setSelectorPosition(
                                newX, newY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight
                            )
                        }

                        else -> {
                            isDragging.value = true
                            setSelectorPosition(
                                x = change.position.x, y = change.position.y, sizeWidth, sizeHeight
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    val touchXBitmap = calculateTouchBitmap(
                        selectorPosition = selectorPositionX.floatValue,
                        sizeBitmap = bitmap.value.width.toFloat(),
                        size = size.width.toFloat()
                    ).toInt()

                    val touchYBitmap = calculateTouchBitmap(
                        selectorPosition = selectorPositionY.floatValue,
                        sizeBitmap = bitmap.value.height.toFloat(),
                        size = size.height.toFloat()
                    ).toInt()

                    val pixelColorInt = bitmap.value.getPixel(touchXBitmap, touchYBitmap)
                    onColorPicked(Color(pixelColorInt))
                }
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = { offset ->
                    setSelectorPosition(offset.x, offset.y, sizeWidth, sizeHeight)

                    val touchXBitmap = calculateTouchBitmap(
                        selectorPosition = selectorPositionX.floatValue,
                        sizeBitmap = bitmap.value.width.toFloat(),
                        size = size.width.toFloat()
                    ).toInt()

                    val touchYBitmap = calculateTouchBitmap(
                        selectorPosition = selectorPositionY.floatValue,
                        sizeBitmap = bitmap.value.height.toFloat(),
                        size = size.height.toFloat()
                    ).toInt()

                    val pixelColorInt = bitmap.value.getPixel(touchXBitmap, touchYBitmap)
                    onColorPicked(Color(pixelColorInt))
                })
            }
            .drawBehind {
                val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(bitmap.value)
                val drawRectF = RectF(0F, 0F, sizeWidth, sizeHeight)
                val hueValue = android.graphics.Color.HSVToColor(floatArrayOf(hue, 1F, 0F))

                val horizontalGradientPaint = LinearGradient(
                    drawRectF.left,
                    drawRectF.top,
                    drawRectF.right,
                    drawRectF.top,
                    -0x1,
                    hueValue,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
                )
                val verticalGradientPaint = LinearGradient(
                    drawRectF.left, drawRectF.top, drawRectF.left, drawRectF.bottom,
                    -0x1,
                    -0x1000000,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                )

                canvas.drawRect(
                    drawRectF,
                    Paint()
                        .asFrameworkPaint()
                        .apply {
                            shader = ComposeShader(
                                verticalGradientPaint,
                                horizontalGradientPaint,
                                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
                            )
                            isAntiAlias = true
                            isDither = true
                        }
                )

                drawImage(
                    bitmap.value.asImageBitmap()
                )

                drawCircle(
                    color = strokeUpdateColor(
                        selectorPositionX.floatValue,
                        selectorPositionY.floatValue,
                        sizeWidth,
                        sizeHeight
                    ),
                    radius = selectorSize,
                    style = Stroke(
                        width = selectorSize / 3.2F,
                    ),
                    center = Offset(selectorPositionX.floatValue, selectorPositionY.floatValue)
                )

            }
        )
    }
}



private fun calculateTouchBitmap(
    selectorPosition: Float,
    sizeBitmap: Float,
    size: Float,
): Float {
    return (selectorPosition * sizeBitmap / size).coerceIn(
        0F, sizeBitmap - 1
    )
}


private fun strokeUpdateColor(
    selectorPositionX: Float,
    selectorPositionY: Float,
    sizeWidth: Float,
    sizeHeight: Float
): Color {
    return if (selectorPositionX >= (sizeWidth / 2)) {
        Color.White
    } else if (selectorPositionY >= (sizeHeight / 2)) {
        Color.White
    } else if (selectorPositionX <= 0F) {
        Color.Black
    } else {
        Color.Black
    }
}
```

Thanks devlopers...

I found the problem of vertical gradient from white to black + horizontal gradient of the specific color, which produced an smath shadow after a little research and caused that the number of px in bitmap and because of the accuracy of the image in bitmap and also in the number of Dpi